# Why is my Swift UI Api fetching code not working

Tags: api, swiftui

I am very new to swift ui so this is probably something very dumb that i missed. I am trying to make a program that gets the current weather description from the “current weather” OpenWeatherMap api. I followed [this](https://youtu.be/-gNOVDNWmIg) api tutorial and was able to get it to function with the giphy api used in the video, but when I tried to adapt it for the weather api it stoped functioning. There are no errors, just the button does nothing. Thanks in advance:)

Api response:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -122.08,
    "lat": 37.39
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 282.55,
    "feels_like": 281.86,
    "temp_min": 280.37,
    "temp_max": 284.26,
    "pressure": 1023,
    "humidity": 100
  },
  "visibility": 16093,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 1.5,
    "deg": 350
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 1
  },
  "dt": 1560350645,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5122,
    "message": 0.0139,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1560343627,
    "sunset": 1560396563
  },
  "timezone": -25200,
  "id": 420006353,
  "name": "Mountain View",
  "cod": 200
  }
```

My code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentWeather = String()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(currentWeather)")
        Button("fetch weather"){fetchAPI()}
    }
    func fetchAPI() {
        let url = URL(string:"api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Raleigh&appid=(ApiKey)")
            //api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedWeather = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherStructure.self, from: data){
                    self.currentWeather = decodedWeather.weather.discription
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct WeatherStructure: Decodable {
    let weather: dataStructure
}

struct dataStructure: Decodable {
    let discription: String
}
```

[Api documentation](https://openweathermap.org/current)

Comment: "Also I don’t really care if you use my api key": do not trust random people on the internet, that's for sure :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

1. `weather` should be an array, since the JSON has an array.
2. `description` was spelt incorrectly as `discription`.
3. The URL **must** start with `https://`.

You need to change your `Decodable` `struct`s to this:

```
struct WeatherStructure: Decodable {
    let weather: [DataStructure]
}

struct DataStructure: Decodable {
    let description: String
}
```

Which also results in this line changing:

```
decodedWeather.weather.description
```

And the URL changed to:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Raleigh&appid=APP_ID")
```

*Note: I also renamed `dataStructure` to `DataStructure`, since in Swift you should start `struct` names with a capital letter.*

Comment: Thank you for this, it still doesn’t appear to be working. The button still does nothing when I press it

Comment: Just to confirm, the only change with the url line is the addition of the https://. Because if so, it still isn’t working for me

Comment: @MalachyFernandez Works perfectly for me with the addition of `https://`, even with your API key.

Comment: Hmmm. That’s weird.

Comment: @MalachyFernandez If my answer helped, an upvote & accept answer would be appreciated!

Comment: sorry. I forgot to accept the answer. I haven't used stackoverflow enough to upvote, sorry

Comment: @MalachyFernandez No problem, it was just a prompt so if people find this question in the future they know it was a useful answer.

Comment: why when I change “let description: String” to “let icon: String” and change “self.currentWeather = decodedWeather.weather.description” to “self.currentWeather = decodedWeather.weather.icon” do I get the error “value of type [DataStructure] has no member ‘icon’”?

Comment: @MalachyFernandez Actually you shouldn't even be able to do `decodedWeather.weather.description`, since `weather` is an array. `description` was only a property from `DataStructure`. To fix your problem, you need to specify the index, e.g. `decodedWeather.weather[0].icon`

Comment: ah thank you, if I wanted to access “temp”, I would think to replace `let weather: [DataStructure]` with `let main: DataStructure` and replace `let description: String` with `let temp: String`. I would also think to replace `self.currentWeather = decodedWeather.weather[0].icon` with `self.currentWeather = decodedWeather.main.temp`. But for some reason this doesn’t work, and the button does nothing, do you know what I am missing?

Comment: @MalachyFernandez Your JSON data is an array, which is why `weather` was `[DataStructure]` (an array). If you are still unsure, just ask another stack overflow question with all the details

Comment: But main isn’t an array, right? Only weather is, so I wouldn’t add that

Comment: @MalachyFernandez Ah, I see `main` isn't array in JSON. `temp` is a `Double`, not a `String`